# Object does not create when using one as global variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, global-variables

I have wrapper class over `Thread`:

```
public class ThreadWrapper
    {
        private bool Terminated = false;
        private string threadName;
        private Thread _thread;

        public bool needToTerminate
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    return Terminated;
                }
            }
        }

        public string ThreadName
        {
            get
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    return threadName;
                }
            }
        }

        // for override constructor in derived classes
        public ThreadWrapper()
        {
        }

        public ThreadWrapper(string threadName)
        {
            this.threadName = threadName;
        }

        public virtual void Run()
        {
        }

        public virtual void Terminate()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                Terminated = true;
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (_thread == null)
                {
                    _thread = new Thread(Run);
                    _thread.Start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i create derived class from `ThreadWrapper`:

```
public delegate void ProcessMessageDelegate(string message);

public class Reader : ThreadWrapper
{
    private ProcessMessageDelegate ProcessMessage;

    public Reader(ProcessMessageDelegate processMessage)
        : base() 
    {
        this.ProcessMessage = processMessage;
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Also i have Form with two buttons. The first button for start thread, the second button for "self-terminate" thread.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private MyReader Reader;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // real method for delegate
        private void ProcessMessage(string message)
        {
            // add line to RichEdit
            this.AddSpRRecordLog(message);
        }

        private void buttonRunTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyReader == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
                return;
            }

            MyReader.Start();
        }

        private void buttonStopTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyReader == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
                return;
            }

            MyReader.Terminate();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reader MyReader = new Reader(new ProcessMessageDelegate(ProcessMessage));               
        }
```

If i use this way (create `MyReader` on `FormLoad` event) - `MyReader` does not create. If i create read in `buttonRunTest_Click` then everything is ok, but in this case i can't terminate `MyReader`.

Comment: You've declared `Reader MyReader` locally and then check a form level field called `Reader`. I don't understand how the code you posted works. The class is named `Reader`, you've got a check for `MyReader == null` though there's no declaration of that, and you've got a field declared as: `private MyReader Reader;` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declares a local variable called `MyReader` that hides the `MyReader` field:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reader MyReader = new Reader(new ProcessMessageDelegate(ProcessMessage));               
    }
```

Instead, just assign to the field:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyReader = new Reader(new ProcessMessageDelegate(ProcessMessage));               
    }
```

(Incidentally, this isn't a global variable in the conventional sense - if another instance of `MainForm` is created, it would have its own independent `MyReader` field)

Comment: Actually -- it didn't shadow it. As I mentioned in my comment, the posted code didn't/doesn't make sense.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - having checked the language spec, hide seems to be a better word than shadows, so I've edited it. But the issue is the one I try to highlight - that there's a local variable in one method and a field with the same name, and so the assignment to the local variable has no effect on the field.

Comment: `private MyReader Reader;` and `Reader MyReader`. One class is `Reader` and the other is `MyReader`. I'm not sure how the code compiled. :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie - ah yes, I see what you mean (I've just been staring at VB code for a while so didn't see that the field declaration is the wrong way around also)